# How to change the figure size of a bar chart to see all values without overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to change the size and also color of this bar chart, so the values don't overlap. Any good suggestions on how to use it with this code?

```
df1.user.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind = 'barh')
```

[image]

Comment: Try setting the graph size and changing the aspect ratio. `df1.user.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind = 'barh', figsize=(6,8))`